# React Native Specifying Style for Sub-Compoennts

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following component:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {


            return (

                <Text>MAIN DASHBOARD</Text>

            );

        };


}
```

Which I am declaring as:

```
 <View style={styles.dashboard}><Dashboard/></View>
```

When I declare my styles I have:

```
dashboard: {

    flex:3

},
```

Now, assume that I wanted to be able to style different sub-components in different ways, for example having my Dashboard component return two views:

```
<View class="a"><Text>View A</Text>
<View class="b"><Text>View B</Text>
```

What I'd like to achieve is a css equivalent of:

```
Dashboard>View.a - {/*props of views with class 'a' which are children of a dashboard element/*}
Dashboard>View.b - {/* Same but for class b /*}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding exactly what you want to do...Is the amount of subcomponents in your Dashboard going to change or is it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Native style system doesn't really have the concept of classes and cascading styles, as in your example. If you are in control of all the child components, you can simply pass arbitrary style objects to your parent `Dashboard` component and then pass those to the children:

```
<Dashboard aStyle={{}} bStyle={{}} />
```

And in your Dashboard view:

```
return (
  <View>
    <AView style={this.props.aStyle} />
    <BView style={this.props.bStyle} />
  </View>
)
```

For more flexible theming support, you could also use the [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) library, which allows you to specify a [Theme](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components#theming) for a certain subtree of your application, and then consume those theme values in any of the children.

That, however, might be overkill for your use case, and you can get by with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)